# Wrong page returned using jQuery.get()

Tags: jquery, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5 and JA K2 Filter and Search component. I am trying to modify the module. When I select a category it should display another file called `custom.html`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //disable the dynamic select list
    jQuery('#extraList').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    //hide the dynamic select list
    jQuery('#extraList').hide();

    WireEvents();
});

function WireEvents() {
    jQuery('#category_id').change(function() {
        var value = jQuery('#category_id').val();
        if (value > 0) {
            //show the dynamic list
            jQuery('#extraList').removeAttr('disabled');
            jQuery('#extraList').show();

            jQuery.get("<?php dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . 'custom.html'; ?>",
                    function(data) {                             
                        jQuery('#outPutDiv').html(data);
                    }
            );

        } else {
            //disable the dynamic list
            jQuery('#extraList').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            //hide the dynamic list
            jQuery('#extraList').hide();
        }

    });
}
</script>
```

The problem is, that instead of returning `custom.html` it returns the home page? How can fix I it?
This are some screenshots: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the PHP documentation `dirname()` only returns the parent directory's path. But iirc the modules are located in `joomla_root/modules/module_name` and that's missing in your request. You can either prepend the missing path by hand or use Joomla's constants for that (`JPATH_SITE . '/modules/module_name/dirname(__FILE__)'` should work iirc).